# How to remove a container disk and reclaim space with boot partision?

Tags: macos, partition, apfs

I want to delete Apple_APFS container `disk1` and reclaim the space to `disk2`.

I boot on `disk2` (Macintosh HD).

[image]

Comment: Have you tried using the Disk Utility GUI? I think you can easily remove a container therein.

Comment: Yes I've tried, when I delete the specific container it automatically creates a new volume with another name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a duplicate question, however I will still post this answer.

The steps are not obvious.

1. Use the `diskutil` command to convert the `disk1` APFS container to an empty JHFS+ formatted partition.

   ```
   sudo diskutil apfs deletecontainer disk0s3
   ```
2. Remove the JHFS+ formatted partition `disk0s3`. The free space will not belong to any partition.

   ```
   sudo diskutil erasevolume free none disk0s3
   ```
3. Expand the `disk2` container to reclaim the just created free space. The value of `0` means to reclaim as much free space as exists directly after the `disk0s2` APFS container partition.

   ```
   sudo diskutil apfs resizecontainer disk0s2 0
   ```

Comment: Yes I know, tried it but didn't work out! Maybe because I didn't use the sudo command, thanks!